# Bluetooth audio devices stop working after a few minutes

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, catalina

Update Dec 3: I keep experiencing this issue whenever there's little memory left. I.e., Bluetooth audio stops behaving correctly whenever Memory Pressure in Activity Monitor is high; the only way to get it working again afterwards is to disable and re-enable Bluetooth.

When I connect an audio device and use it to play music, audio stops working after a few minutes and switches to internal speakers instead (but the device continues to be shown as "Connected" in Bluetooth). This happens with all my Bluetooth audio devices (3 in total). I don't experience any of these issues when using the same devices with my smartphone. The issue started around a month ago, roughly at the time when I upgraded to macOS Catalina. I'm using a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015).

I have tried the following steps already:

- Moving my bluetooth device right next to my laptop
- Updating to macOS Catalina 10.15.1
- Disabling and enabling Bluetooth
- Restarting the laptop
- Removing and re-adding all Bluetooth devices
- Deleting the file "com.apple.Bluetooth.plist" in /Library/Preferences/
- Resetting PRAM
- Searching StackExchange and the internet for more advice

None of these have helped, not even temporarily.

This is what it looks like when the issue is present:

[image]

When hovering over the audio device, its name disappears; when clicking it, the audio menu bar icon becomes animated and looks like it's searching/loading in a way I haven't seen before.

At the same time, the device looks normal in Bluetooth:

[image]

[image]

I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I tried a whole bunch of additional things that are related to sound rather than bluetooth. The issue is now resolved. I don't know which of the steps fixed it but if you have the same issue, doing all of them will likely resolve it:

**1. Reload coreaudiod**

Enter the following into Terminal:

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod.plist
```

Then restart the laptop (or do step 3 (below) at the same time).

I got errors when doing the above, but perhaps it still helped somehow.

**2. Unload the kernel extension**

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext 
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
```

Again, I got errors when doing the above, but perhaps it still helped somehow.

**3. Reset the SMC**

Shut down the laptop, connect it to power, hold the four buttons cmd-option-shift-power for at least 10 seconds, release, start the laptop again.

--

After performing these steps, everything was back to normal.

Comment: Update: The issues just started occurring again, so it seems like this isn't a permanent fix.

Comment: Update Dec 3: I keep experiencing this issue whenever there's little memory left. I.e., Bluetooth audio stops behaving correctly whenever Memory Pressure in Activity Monitor is high; the only way to get it working again afterwards is to disable and re-enable Bluetooth.

Comment: This should be fixed in macOS 10.15.3 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251061620

Comment: Cool, thanks. I noticed the issue occurs whenever there's a lot of memory pressure. I ended up buying a new laptop with 4x as much RAM partly because of this issue, but glad to hear it's now fixed on the software side.