# All bluetooth devices disconnect suddenly

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, bluetooth

Sometimes all bluetooth devices get disconnected. My Apple mouse & keyboard reconnect automatically. My headset needs a manual reconnect.

Device: MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2016)

OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.3

Comment: Did you check this https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/375064/341892

Comment: Yeh, already struggled with that too but it's solved since Catalina 10.15.3 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251061620?page=1

Comment: I have the same issue - and suspecting that the devices disconnect when the available memory is low. Keep the activity monitor open on the tab "memory" see if the devices disconnect when the memory usage is high - and maybe also dropped quickly after. This reminds me of Linux, which (when the memory is low) selects and kills certain applications. I'm already on 10.5.3 - so I'm facing a different issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm monitoring the memory usage and here there's no high pressure when they disconnect. Before macOS 10.15.3 it did but bluetooth didn't disconnect, just audio stopped sending to bluetooth.